# Grafana with PCP + Redis collecting and storing metrics set up using a RHEL Ansible role metrics - Some metrics for NVIDIA not showing up in Grafana

Tags: redis, grafana, nvidia, metrics

I am currently using the Ansible Role Metrics to collect performance metrics. It uses performance co pilot and redis to visualize these metrics on Grafana. The issue I am having is specifically with metrics being collected on the NVIDIA GPUs in certain systems I am monitoring. I have set up the Ansible role to install and enable the nvidia pmda only on systems that have nvidia GPUs installed on them. I have a list of metrics that are in the /var/lib/pcp/config/pmlogger file for that specific system as shows:

```
        nvidia.gpuid
        nvidia.temperature
        nvidia.fanspeed
        nvidia.perfstate
        nvidia.memfree
        nvidia.carduuid
        nvidia.energy
        nvidia.power
        nvidia.proc.samples
        nvidia.proc.memused
        nvidia.proc.memaccum
        nvidia.proc.gpuactive
        nvidia.proc.memactive
        nvidia.proc.time
        nvidia.proc.running
        nvidia.proc.all.samples
        nvidia.proc.all.memused
        nvidia.proc.all.memaccum
        nvidia.proc.all.gpuactive
        nvidia.proc.all.memactive
        nvidia.proc.all.time
        nvidia.proc.all.running
        nvidia.proc.all.gpulist
        nvidia.proc.all.ngpus
        nvidia.proc.compute.samples
        nvidia.proc.compute.memused
        nvidia.proc.compute.memaccum
        nvidia.proc.compute.gpuactive
        nvidia.proc.compute.memactive
        nvidia.proc.compute.time
        nvidia.proc.compute.running
        nvidia.proc.compute.gpulist
        nvidia.proc.compute.ngpus
        nvidia.proc.graphics.samples
        nvidia.proc.graphics.memused
        nvidia.proc.graphics.memaccum
        nvidia.proc.graphics.gpuactive
        nvidia.proc.graphics.memactive
        nvidia.proc.graphics.time
        nvidia.proc.graphics.running
        nvidia.proc.graphics.gpulist
        nvidia.proc.graphics.ngpus
```

The problem is when I go to query the redis pcp datasource only a handful of these metrics will show up as options for the query. Basically I have no issues with any other metrics besides nvidia. Does anyone know of this happening or have any suggestions as to why this may be happening?

I have checked multiple times that the pmda is working and enabled, and everything seems to check out with pcp working as it should be.